# How to get the number of words per line in pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I'm trying to figure out how many words their are per line in a file in pig. I've gotten as far as loading and splitting:

```
raw = load file;
words = FOREACH raw GENERATE TOKENIZE(*);
```

which gets me a bag of tulples each containing a word. Then I go to count these items I get an error:

```
counts = FOREACH words GENERATE COUNT(*);
```

I get an error:

```
org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2106: Error while computing count in COUNT
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

is that because some of the lines have an empty bag? or is there something else I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should not use COUNT(*) like this, this is restricted in Pig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it is the problem with an empty bag then you can try something like this: (Not tested)

```
raw = load file;

words = FOREACH raw GENERATE TOKENIZE(*) as tokenized_words;

counts = FOREACH words GENERATE ((tokenized_words IS null or TRIM(tokenized_words) == '') ? 0 : COUNT(*)) as total_count;
```

here we are writing if-else condition to check if the tokenized_words is null or empty, if yes then we are assigning zero to it else the total count.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this?

**input**

```
Hi hello how are you
this is apache pig
works

like a charm
```

**Pigscript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input' AS (line:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE TOKENIZE(line);
C = FOREACH B GENERATE COUNT($0);
DUMP C;
```

**Output:**

```
(5)
(4)
(1)
()
(3)
```